# Chapman-Kolmogorov equation for conditional probabilities?

Tags: stochastic-processes

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapman%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_equation) (note that I have modified it from for a Markov process to for a general stochastic process):

> the conditional probability density $p_{i;j}(f_i\mid f_j)$ is the transition probability between the times $i>j$. So, the Chapman–Kolmogorov equation takes the form
>   $$
>     p_{i_3;i_1}(f_3\mid f_1)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p_{i_3;i_2, i_1}(f_3\mid f_2, f_1)p_{i_2;i_1}(f_2\mid f_1) \, df_2. 
> $$

I was wondering how to rephrase the above equation in terms of conditional probability measures instead of conditional probability densities?

To give you an idea of what I want,  the analogy in the unconditional case, i.e. the case for finite dimensional distributions, is as following:

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapman%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_equation):

> Let
>   $$
>     p_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}(f_1,\ldots,f_n)
> $$
>   be the joint probability density function of the values of the random variables $f_1$ to $f_n$. Then, the Chapman–Kolmogorov equation is
>   $$
>     p_{i_1,\ldots,i_{n-1}}(f_1,\ldots,f_{n-1})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}(f_1,\ldots,f_n)\,df_n 
> $$

It can be written in terms of probability measures, instead of their density functions (also from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem))

> for all measurable sets $F_{i} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n},m \in \mathbb{N}$
>   $$\nu_{t_{1} \dots t_{k}} \left( F_{1} \times \dots \times F_{k} \right) = \nu_{t_{1} \dots t_{k} t_{k + 1}, \dots , t_{k+m}} \left( F_{1} \times \dots \times F_{k} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \dots \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \right). $$

Thanks and regards!